# Making raw SQL safe in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, sql-injection

```
var retval = db.TestTable.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM dbo.TestTable WHERE " + aColumn + " = '" + passedInValue + "'");

// normally when using parameters I would do something like this:
var valueParam = SqlParameter("aValue", passedInValues);
var retval = db.TestTable.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM dbo.TestTable WHERE Column1 = @aValue", valueParam);
// NOTE: I would not do this at all. I know to use LINQ. But for this question, I'm concentrating on the issue of passing variables to a raw sql string.
```

But since both the column and value are "parameters" in:

```
var retval = db.TestTable.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM dbo.TestTable WHERE " + aColumn + " = '" + passedInValue + "'");
```

, is there to prevent sql injection for both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: whilelist `aColumn`: this has to be added via string concatenation but you know what columns are in your database (or you can check using schema views).

Second: In entity framework – as you show – you can use parameters for values in the query. However, rather than creating `SqlParameter` instances you can pass the values and use `@p0`, `@p1`, ….

Comment: Can you expand on the first part of your answer? What do you mean by 'whilelist `aColumn`?

Comment: @DaBest Whitelist column: fail if `aColumn` is not an exact match in your list of known columns: `if (!safeColumList.Contains(aColumn)) throw new SecurityException("Hacker!!");`.

Answer (score 0):

Right way to prevent SQL injection is to use `SqlParameter` and `SqlQuery<T>`:

```
var parameter = new SqlParameter("@title", value);
var result = context.Database.SqlQuery<Book>("SELECT * FROM Books WHERE Title LIKE @title", parameter);
```

http://ignoringthevoices.blogspot.ru/2013/07/sql-injection-with-entity-framework-5.html